# C++ why setWindowText doesn't display any text?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have code as below, and my question is why in the cell A[0][0] setWindowText put nothing?

```
if(LOWORD( wParam ) == 104){
    int td;
    int td_width=80;
    int tr = 0;
    int tr_height=20; 

    for (tr=0;tr<2;tr++) {
        for (td=0;td<10;td++) {
            HWND A[tr][td];

            A[tr][td] = CreateWindowEx( 0, "EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
td*td_width, tr*tr_height+50, td_width+1, tr_height+1, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
        }
        SetWindowText(A[0][0], "MK" );
    }

}
```

Comment: Slightly odd that you attempt to set the window text 20 times in the same control.

Comment: I want to do few cells like in excel with unique "id" for each.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lol only slightly ? =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter said, you are declaring your array in the wrong spot.  But more than that, you are also declaring the array as fixed-length but using run-time values to specify its bounds. That will not work, and should not even compile.  A fixed-length array's bounds must be known at compile-time, not at run-time.

Try this instead:

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == 104)
{
    const int td_width = 80;
    const int tr_height = 20; 

    HWND A[2][10];

    for (int tr = 0; tr < 2; ++tr)
    {
        for (int td = 0; td < 10; ++td)
        {
            A[tr][td] = CreateWindowEx( 0, TEXT("EDIT"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, td*td_width, tr*tr_height+50, td_width+1, tr_height+1, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
        }
    }

    SetWindowText(A[0][0], TEXT("MK") );
}
```

Comment: Thats what I need:) Thank You! The best way to learn is just give an example:)

Answer (score 4):

You're defining A[tr][td] inside the inner most loop.  This restricts its scope to just that loop.  In other words, on each iteration, you're creating a brand new array and assigning just one of its elements.

It's a little surprising that this even compiles.  I guess you have *another* A array defined somewhere else, and that's the one you're referencing in the SetWindowText call.